# How to add or delete crontab entry without python-crontab module

Tags: python, cron

To start, I cannot install new python modules and have to work with what is there already.
So I want to add or delete entries in the crontab with my python script and have to pass arguments thru.
As python-crontab is not an option I have to work with `os`, `sys`, `subprocess` and `shlex`.

I have tried to following:

```
commandstring = '(crontab -l 2>/dev/null; echo "0 5 5 5 * '/bin/date +%Y` == 2017 && /bin/touch filename") | crontab -'
subprocess.call(shlex.split(commandstring))
```

But gives me an error back. Maybe I don't understand how the shlex works and how to format the string.
Or there might be a better way to do this.

What i want to achieve is that i want to use cron to create files with specific filenames and the touch command at a specific date/time and delete those file as a specific date/time. "at" is also not installed, so i have to use cron.

It seems like `shell.py` would be the right way, but as I cannot install new modules, same problem as with python-crontab.

Comment: It looks like syntax highlighting already shows the problem.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python